# A tabbed UI for child entries

Tags: entries, loop

wonder if a guru could help, I am nearly there, just stuck on the right call.

Building a standard css/jquery responsive tab solution. I am pulling back child entries to populate a parent page with said tabs. The problem is the for loop, not being able to close the unordered list before the next part. I wonder if anyone could help please.

```
    <!-- Tabs -->
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('country').level(3) %}
<ul class="tabs">

{% for entry in entries %}
<li {% if loop.first %} class="" {% else %} class="active" {% endif %} rel="{{ loop.index }}">{{entry.pageTitle}}</li>

</ul>

<div class="tab_container">

<!-- start tab -->
<h3 {% if loop.first %} class="d_active tab_drawer_heading"  {% else %} class="tab_drawer_heading" {% endif %}  rel="{{ loop.index }}">{{entry.pageTitle}}</h3>
<div id="{{ loop.index }}" class="tab_content">
{{entry.pageTitle}}
</div>
<!-- end tab -->
{% endfor %}
</div><!-- .tab_container -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for two loops to make it easier to maintain sanity later on:

```
<!-- Tabs -->
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('country').level(3) %}
<ul class="tabs">
   {% for entry in entries %}   
   <li class="{% if loop.first %}active{% endif %}" rel="{{ loop.index }}">{{entry.pageTitle}}</li>
   {% endif %}
</ul>


<!-- Tab_container -->
<div class="tab_container">
   {% for entry in entries %}  
   <h3 class="{% if loop.first %}d_active{% endif %} tab_drawer_heading" rel="{{ loop.index }}">{{entry.pageTitle}}</h3>
   <div id="{{ loop.index }}" class="tab_content">
      {{entry.pageTitle}}
   </div>
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```